# Board and batten siding material

Tags: siding

I'm considering board and batten siding. In my area cedar and hardie are the most common, but I don't really want to break the bank on either of those at this time. What other materials can I use for the boards in board and batten siding? If I'm painting it can I use plywood?

Comment: sure why not.  what thickness 3/4"?  are you doing vertical pattern / what is your proud vs shy ratio?  is your rainscreen 1/2 or 3/4" pt strips?  will you do horizontal strips on top of your rainscreen for nailers?  do you have metal through flashing headers with back dams for your windows / penetrations?

Comment: _what thickness 3/4"?_ **3/4"** | _are you doing vertical pattern / what is your proud vs shy ratio?_ **a vertical pattern and I'm not sure what proud vs shy refers to exactly, but if it's the width of the board vs the batten I was planning on 10" & 3"** | _is your rainscreen 1/2 or 3/4" pt strips?_ **I think 1/2" but I'm not 100% sure** | _will you do horizontal strips on top of your rainscreen for nailers?_ **yes, I was planning on it** | _do you have metal through flashing headers with back dams for your windows / penetrations?_ **I will, yes**

Comment: WRT the question "why not". I'm not sure why not, I've been searching the internet for that and haven't found any information. I assumed it was possible, but I'm trying to answer that question for myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used plywood as the board in part of my board batten install.  I was doing cedar with a clear coat.  I used minwax spar urethane to coat the cedar and the plywood.  The plywood went moldy in the first year mostly noticeable on the lighter areas of the ply.

If you are painting your board and batten I think you can use any wood.  It is just going to be painful to cut the plywood into the strips.  Normally someone doing siding calculates time and material into their equation and the time would dictate ordering something pre-cut from a lumber yard.

The other issue you'll run into is height.  If you are going vertical then you probably need 10' strips so then you are looking at ordering 10'x8' sheets of plywood.  I suspect if you cost this out then even before cutting your sheets of plywood are going to cost more than if you bought 1x4 @ 10' and 1x12 @ 10' of pine.  Plywood is going to be more dimensionally stable but with paint grade material you can use whatever fasteners you want and make sure the wood can't move.

[image: cedar board and batten]

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question that I had exactly.